# Синтаксическая ошибка RedBean

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Написал такое:

```php
<?php 

require_once "rb/rb.php";

R::setup('mysql: host = 127.0.0.1; dbname = rb_test', 'root', '');

if (!R::testConnection()) {
    exit('Нет подключения к базе данных!');
}

// CREATE

$user = R::dispense('user');

$user -> name = 'Hugo';
$user -> age = 27;
$user -> country = 'USA';

R::store($user);

?>
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught [3D000] - SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected trace: #0 C:\Users\kamah\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\redbean\rb\rb.php(1080): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery('show tables', Array) #1 C:\Users\kamah\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\redbean\rb\rb.php(1101): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetAll('show tables', Array) #2 C:\Users\kamah\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\redbean\rb\rb.php(4267): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetCol('show tables', Array) #3 C:\Users\kamah\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\redbean\rb\rb.php(6834): RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->getCol('show tables') #4 C:\Users\kamah\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\redbean\rb\rb.php(6001): RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\MySQL->getTables() #5 C:\Users\kamah\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\redbean\rb\rb.php(9127): RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\AQueryWriter->tableExists('user') #6 C:\Users\kamah\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\redbean\rb\rb.php(9229): RedBeanPHP\Repository->tableExists('user') #7 C:\Users\kamah\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\redbean\rb\rb.php(9361): RedBeanPHP\Repository\Fluid->createTableIf in C:\Users\kamah\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\redbean\rb\rb.php on line 810

Скачивал RedBean с официального сайта, со всеми драйверами
Я думаю, что у меня проблема с синтаксисом, который я плохо знаю.
Есть ли ресурс, где можно посмотреть примеры того, как вызывать функции в ReadBean, типа www.php.net, только для ReadBean??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ошибки начинаются, только после того, как я напишу `R::store($user);`, если убрать эту строчку, ошибок нету
Использую OpenServer в такой конфигурации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выкладывайте структуру Вашего проекта. Не корректно указали путь.

Comment: @Denis640Kb В корне сайта есть index.php и папка rb, в папке rb есть два файла - rb.php и файл с лицензией redbean

Comment: и называется Ваша база точно rb_test? И ещё, раз уж локально висит всё на компе, логично будет указывать mysql:host=localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, вот в чём у меня была ошибка: 
Если написать в `R::setup` вот такой текст `dbname =rb_test` или `dbname= rb_test`,
 или
`dbname = rb_test`, то происходит эта ошибка.
Лучше писать в таком виде, без пробелов и не париться

`R::setup('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=rb_test','root','');`

Answer (score 0):

Перебор с пробелами ))) Предполагается, что Вы создали Базу данных и логин с паролем верные. Переходим к созданию таблицы.

Вот рабочий пример:

```php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: 640kb
 * Date: 03/01/2020
 * Time: 22:54
 */

require_once "../rb.php";

R::setup('mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=rb_test', 'root', '');

if (!R::testConnection()) {
    exit('Нет подключения к базе данных!');
}

// CREATE


$user = R::dispense('user1');
$user->name = 'Hugo';
$user->age = 27;
$user->country = 'USA';
R::store($user);
```